# getaddrinfo, bind, localhost and INADDR_ANY

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, getaddrinfo

I'm learning socket programing and pretty new to this...
My question is, I want to write a UDP server that is able to receive packets from both remote server and local host via a OS-assigned socket.

I know I should somehow pass `INADDR_ANY` to bind() to let it accept packet from both. and I **guess** I need to pass `char *service=NULL` to `getaddrinfo` so that it will assign a port. However, I don't know if so what to do with the `node` parameter of `getaddrinfo`.

According to `getaddrino` [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) page, `node` and `service` cannot both be NULL, yet the `INADDR_ANY` will only be set in the returned socket address when (1) `hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE` and **(2) `node` is set to NULL**. I'm confused with this confliction..
And since "have an OS-assigned port" is the assignment requirement, I can't change the `service` I guess.

I read that INADDR_ANY is basically `0.0.0.0`, does that mean I can just pass this string as `node`?

Any comment is welcomed!

Comment: What happens if you just call `listen` without first calling `bind`?

Comment: `getaddrinfo` does not assign anything. It only looks up well-known ports. There is no law that makes it illegal to call `bind()` to bind to specific port without calling `getaddrinfo` first. You are free to call `bind()` to bind to a specific port on `INADDR_ANY`. The End.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `getaddrinfo()` that assigns a random available port.  It is `bind()` that does so when port 0 is requested.

The `getaddrinfo()` man page is correct.  The `node` and `service` parameters cannot both be `NULL` at the same time.  You can set node to `NULL` to get `INADDR_ANY` - or - you can set `service` to `NULL` to get port 0.  But, to get both, you will have to either:

- set `node` to `NULL`, `service` to `"0"`, and `hints.ai_flags` to `AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV`.
- set `node` to `"0.0.0.0"` and `service` to `NULL` (`AI_PASSIVE` is ignored)
- set `node` to `"0.0.0.0"`, `service` to `"0"`, and `hints.ai_flags` to `AI_NUMERICSERV` (`AI_PASSIVE` is ignored)

Any of those combinations will cause `getaddrinfo()` to return a pointer to a `sockaddr_in` that has its `sin_addr` set to `INADDR_ANY` and its `sin_port` set to `0`.

You can then `bind()` using that `sockaddr_in`, and `bind()` will choose a random available port, which you can retrieve using `getsockname()` afterwards.

```c
int server_fd = -1;

struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

struct addrinfo *result;
if( getaddrinfo(NULL, "0", &hints, &result) != 0 )
{
    // error handling...
}
else if( (server_fd = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol)) < 0 )
{
    // error handling...
    freeaddrinfo(result);
}
else if( bind(server_fd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) < 0 )
{
    // error handling...
    close(server_fd);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
}
else
{
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // use server_fd as needed...

    struct sockaddr_in bound_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(bound_addr); 
  
    if( getsockname(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&bound_addr, &addrlen) < 0 )
    {
        // error handling...
    } 
    else
    {
        // use ntohs(bound_addr.sin_port) as needed...
    }

    ...

    close(server_fd);
}
```

Or, since you know exactly what you want to `bind()` to, you can simply ignore `getaddrinfo()` and populate a `sockaddr_in` manually:

```c
int server_fd;

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.sin_port = 0;

if( (server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 )
{
    // error handling...
}
else if( bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0 )
{
    // error handling...
    close(server_fd);
}
else
{
    // use server_fd as needed...

    struct sockaddr_in bound_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(bound_addr); 
  
    if( getsockname(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&bound_addr, &addrlen) < 0 )
    {
        // error handling...
    } 
    else
    {
        // use ntohs(bound_addr.sin_port) as needed...
    }

    ...

    close(server_fd);
}
```

Comment: great answer! thanks so much! Just one more question: so does that mean when writing the server end, we don't really need `getaddrino` since we know both the host IP (INADDR_ANY) and the port (any one available), and `getaddrinfo` is only needed on client side to determine the IP according to the host name (e.g. www.google.com)

Comment: @Crystina commonly, yes. Though getaddrinfo does have uses on the server end, such as when combining AI_PASSIVE with a specific IP or port, and/or with AF_UNSPEC to create binding sockets for both IPv4 and IPv6.